# How can I prevent Outlook from adding junk e-mail lists to the server?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange, spam-prevention

When I start up Outlook 2007, and sometimes while it's running, I get the following message:

> Cannot add to the server Junk E-mail Lists, you are over the size allowed on the server. The Junk E-mail Filter on the server will be disabled until your Junk E-mail Lists have been reduced to the size allowed on the server.
>
> Would you like to manage your Junk E-mail Lists now?
>
> <kbd>Manage Lists...</kbd>  <kbd>Cancel</kbd>

The first time this error occurred I had only one entry in my "Blocked Senders" list from several months ago, which I have since removed.  The "Safe Senders" and "Safe Recipients" lists are also empty, as are my "Blocked Top-Level Domain List" and my "Blocked Encodings List".  I cannot disable Junk E-mail filtering, it is greyed out in the options.  The option "Also trust e-mail from my Contacts" is selected in the Safe Senders tab of the options.

Is there any way I can prevent Outlook from attempting to add whatever lists these are to the server?  Is there any other way to fix this?  It's probably not a server problem since no one else is encountering this, and I'd prefer a quick client-side fix over going through IT anyways.  I believe the server is running Exchange 2007, and there are no other clients in use, set up, or supported besides my BlackBerry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option "Also trust e-mail from my Contacts" is what makes the "Safe Senders" list exceed the total limit.

You can try changing the [limit of the junk e-mail lists](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=842510), listed at the bottom of the page.

> By default, you have the following limit on the total size of the junk e-mail lists:
>
> - Exchange: 512 kb (cumulative for all lists combined)
> - POP3/IMAP: none
>
> Therefore, if you are using these lists extensively with an Exchange mailbox, you might hit the 512 KB limit.
>
> **Registry key:** `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSExchangeIS\ParametersSystem`
> **Value:** Max Extended Rule Size
> **Type:** DWORD
> **Data:** maximum size, in bytes, you want to allow for the junk e-mail rule

As you can see, "Max Extended Rule" applies to all rules and not just junk rules.